# How to handle response with <?> type in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There is some third-party function with a method signature.

`public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile()`

Without going into too much detail, this function uploads a file and returns a json response back, with a field containing the word ok.
I know the DTO structure that the function returns when the file is successfully uploaded.
But how do I handle a negative outcome. When does the error return? This example is abstract. But it can be understood that the structure of the erroneous DTO is not equal to the structure of the DTO on a positive outcome.

And I somehow need to check this field, let's call it "status", that it is not null. How can this be done better?

Comment: If you are waiting for some unchecked exception while requesting, you can make GlobalExceptionHandler aspect and catch any exception there

Comment: I mean maybe use something like Optional<>? But how to cast from <? > to <MyType>

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the response to String type first.

```
For example - ResponseEntity<String> resp = uploadfile();
```

Then check the status code for the response.
I am assuming that you will be getting 2xx series for a successful file upload and 4xx series if there is a failure.

Based on the status code you can conditionally map the string response body to whichever DTO you want to map it to.

```
For ex :
 if(resp.getStatusCode()==200)  {
   SuccessDTO s= new 
ObjectMapper().readValue(resp.getBody(),SuccessDTO.class);
}
else
 {
  ErrorDTO s= new 
 ObjectMapper().readValue(resp.getBody(),ErrorDTO.class);
}
```